# Updating column so that it contains the row position

Tags: php, sql, mysql

This is the `content` table:

```
ContentID | CategoryID | Position | Other1 | Other2
===================================================
1         | 1          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
2         | 1          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
3         | 1          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
4         | 2          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
5         | 2          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
6         | 2          | NULL     | abcd   | efgh
```

These are the queries I'll be running:

```sql
SELECT ContentID FROM content WHERE CategoryID = 1 ORDER BY Position
SELECT ContentID FROM content WHERE CategoryID = 2 ORDER BY Position
```

Now I want to implement move up, move down, move to top and move to bottom function for content. All I need to do is to populate the Position column with numbers:

```
ContentID | CategoryID | Position
=================================
1         | 1          | 1
2         | 1          | 2
3         | 1          | 3
4         | 2          | 1
5         | 2          | 2
6         | 2          | 3
```

Is it possible to achieve this via single query in MySQL? Something like:

```sql
UPDATE content
SET Position = <ROW_NUMBER>
WHERE CategoryID = 1
ORDER BY Position

UPDATE content
SET Position = <ROW_NUMBER>
WHERE CategoryID = 2
ORDER BY Position
```

Comment: you could probably use a CASE statement somehow, but two queries may be better.

Comment: @Everyone: I just managed to do that.

Comment: `update content set position = id`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: will work when Position column is blank, but not after user positions some of the items.

Comment: Nor any other proposed solution. it's just for initial filling. To move it up and down after that you will need to run another queries, simple ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```sql
update 
content,
(
  select 
  @row_number:=ifnull(@row_number, 0)+1 as new_position,
  ContentID 
  from content
  where CategoryID=1
  order by position
) as table_position
set position=table_position.new_position
where table_position.ContentID=content.ContentID;
```

But I would prefer to apply this first, to unset user defined variable

```sql
set @row_number:=0;
```

## Added by Mchl:

You can do that in one statement like this

```sql
update 
content,
(
  select 
  @row_number:=ifnull(@row_number, 0)+1 as new_position,
  ContentID 
  from content
  where CategoryID=1
  order by position
) as table_position,
(
  select @row_number:=0
) as rowNumberInit
set position=table_position.new_position
where table_position.ContentID=content.ContentID;
```

Comment: Will test it tomorrow. Can you use the same table in update and select?

Comment: Mchl, I had to swap ()rowNumberInit above ()table_position for this single query to work. As above, new_position always comes out to 1, if ()rowNumberInit is put first, before @row_number is used in ()table_position, new_position gives numbers in order.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me (hope it helps someone):

```sql
-- The following query re-populates the "Position" column with sequential numbers so that:
-- a) sequence is reset to 1 for each "group"
-- b) sequence is based on row number relative to each group depending on how ORDER BY is specified
-- c) sequence does not disturb the original order but
-- c.a) fixes NULLs so that they are moved to top
-- c.b) fixes duplicate position values depending on how ORDER BY is specified

-- ContentID is the primary key
-- CategoryID is a foreign key
-- Position column contains relative position of a record

SET @current_group = NULL;
SET @current_count = NULL;

UPDATE 
content
SET Position = CASE
    WHEN @current_group = CategoryID THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1
    WHEN @current_group := CategoryID THEN @current_count := 1
END
ORDER BY CategoryID, Position -- <Column 3>, <Column 4>, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be very tedious to run additional queries all the time when you do some operations on the table. I would [create](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html) a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) that fires every time you want to insert/update something in the table.

In your case, a `BEFORE UPDATE` and `BEFORE INSERT` trigger would be advisable. If you also want to keep it clean after the deletion of an etntry, add an `AFTER DELETE` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Initial:

```sql
UPDATE content as uc 
SET Position = (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM content as sc 
    WHERE sc.CategoryId = uc.CategoryId AND sc.Position is not null)
WHERE uc.Position is null
ORDER BY uc.ContentId
```

Before insert:

```sql
UPDATE content
SET Position = Position+1
WHERE Position >= newPos AND CategoryId = newCat
```

Comment: Gives me this error `SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'uc' for update in FROM clause`.