# current row id or row number in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get the row id or row number from the result set in php mysql query?
What is the use of _rowid in mysql?

The following query fetch the details of applicant 2435

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE _rowid =2435
```

but here _rowid is not a field of the table. Like this we need to get the record id from a result set in php mysql.

Comment: guess he means, the `SN` of the row or `id` of the table row

Comment: There is no internal rowid in MySQL. Try use PK (+auto_increment)

Comment: @experimentX ...yes, it also can be a rank

Comment: @Faraona - CREATE TABLE table_test(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO table_test (NAME) VALUES ('text1'), ('text2'), ('text3');
SELECT id, name FROM table_test;

Comment: @Devart PK has nothing to do with row number and cannot be used this way

Comment: Ben you have to rephrase your question, to make it more certain, or it will be closed.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel agree about row number. I was about row id.

Comment: The following query fetch the details of applicant 2435 "SELECT *
FROM applications
WHERE _rowid =2435", but here _rowid is not a field of the table. Like this we need to get the record id from a result set in php mysql.

Comment: you have to edit your question instead of commenting it. I did it for you this time. However you can edit it again and add more details. I've never heard of _rowid thing though

Comment: what for do you need this row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this function [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: this function only useful when we insert into table, but not in case of select

Comment: Yes this functions returns id of inserted data into table

Answer (score 4):

Extracted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632696/updating-column-so-that-it-contains-the-row-position):

```
SELECT @row_number := NULL;
SELECT
    @row_number := IFNULL(@row_number, 0) + 1 AS row_number,
    Column1,
    Column2,
    ColumnN
FROM the_table
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY Column1
```

If you are running this query from PHP, you need to execute the `mysql_query()` function twice. First query would be `SELECT @row_number := NULL` and second one would be the `SELECT ...` query. Both queries must be executed together over same connection.