# mysql update a column with an int based on order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, identity

Lets say I have these columns

```
 uniqueID|Money|Quantity|MoneyOrder|QuantityOrder
1|23|12||
2|11|9||
3|99|100||
```

What I want to do is update `MoneyOrder` and `QuantityOrder` based on the value of `ORDER BY`.

So the results would be:

```
uniqueID|Money|Quantity|MoneyOrder|QuantityOrder
1|23|12|2|1
2|11|90|1|2
3|99|100|3|3
```

I want the update to operate like an identity column without actually making it an identity column.  I know that I could just order by 'x' and the order would be the result but I want to generate a report where you can see the item line by line.

Is something like this possible `update mytable set Moneyorder = 'imnotsure' order by MoneyOrder asc` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
SET @rownumber = 0;    
update mytable set Moneyorder = (@rownumber:=@rownumber+1)
order by MoneyOrder asc
```

or to do it in a single query you can try

```
update mytable target
join
(
     select id, (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1) as rownum
     from mytable         
     cross join (select @rownumber := 0) r
     order by MoneyOrder asc
) source on target.id = source.id    
set Moneyorder = rownum
```

Comment: for the second query, throws an error: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Comment: I uodated the query. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 9):

See answers to this question:

[Updating column so that it contains the row position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632696/updating-column-so-that-it-contains-the-row-position)

```
SET @counter = 0;

UPDATE 
my_table
SET MoneyOrder = @counter := @counter + 1
ORDER BY Money;

SET @counter = 0;

UPDATE 
my_table
SET QuantityOrder = @counter := @counter + 1
ORDER BY Quantity;
```