# Inserting new entry and updating a whole column at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a somewhat complex problem that needs fixing, for now I have the following table structure (task_schedule):

```
id   taskid   productid   product_position
1    1        1           1
2    2        1           2
3    3        2           1
4    4        1           3
5    5        2           2
6    6        3           1
```

**product_position** works the following way: it should look at the productid and increment from the previous max value entry.

I accomplish this with the following query (probably easier to understand too):

```
INSERT into task_schedule (taskid, productid, product_position)
SELECT 1,1, max(product_position) + 1
FROM task_schedule
WHERE productid=1
```

(the values are of course attributed in the php backend)

I need a new column now though. Lets call it **user_position**, I'm going to recreate my table with an example:

```
id   taskid   productid   product_position   user_position
1    1        1           1                  1
2    2        1           2                  4
3    3        2           1                  2
4    4        1           3                  6
5    5        2           2                  5
6    6        3           1                  3
```

OK, so how this should work is: user_position should individually run through each entry and look at the productid, it should build a position list based on an even order of priority.

So if I ordered this by user_position I would get the following entry id list: **1 3 6 2 5 4**

An example of what I need done in php:

Imagine the following list: **red red red green green green green blue blue yellow**

```
$array1 = array(array("red"), array("red"), array("red"));

$array2 = array(array("green"), array("green"), array("green"), array("green"));

$array3 = array(array("blue"), array("blue"));

$array4 = array(array("yellow"));

$Arrays= array ($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

foreach ($Arrays as $type => $list) {
    $ArrayLength[]=count($list);
}


$MergeArray=array();
$flag=true;
for($i=0;$flag==true;$i++)
{
    $flag=false;
    for($j=0;$j < count($ArrayLength);$j++)
    {
        if( $i < $ArrayLength[$j] )
        {
           array_push( $MergeArray , $Arrays[$j][$i] );
           $flag=true;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>".Print_r(json_encode($MergeArray), true)."</pre>";
```

This returns me a consistent list with the pattern I desire:

```
[["red"],["green"],["blue"],["yellow"],["red"],["green"],["blue"],["red"],["green"],["green"]]
```

All of the above is just an example of what I need, but implemented via MySQL.

---

I don't even know how to approach this issue now though, I need a way to insert new entries AND update the user_position column accordingly.

If I was to add a new entry into my table, with a new peoduct_id, this should be the end result:

```
id   taskid   productid   product_position   user_position
1    1        1           1                  1
2    2        1           2                  5
3    3        2           1                  2
4    4        1           3                  7
5    5        2           2                  6
6    6        3           1                  3
7    7        4           1                  4
```

Notice how the user_position shifted to accommodate the new row.

I think this is a fairly complex problem to solve (or maybe my mysql is just THAT weak), I don't think there is a easy solution for this one, so any input you might have on how to approach this via mysql (mysql doing the heavy lifting would be fantastic), but I welcome a PHP solution as well with multiple queries and whatnot. Unfortunately I can't drop this column, it's easy to grab entries and let PHP sort my information, but I really need this implemented in the database.

Any input from the community would be great really.

Comment: I have added my logic below..

Comment: How about using MySQL to do the whole work? Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485769/mysql-update-a-column-with-an-int-based-on-order/10485817#10485817) as inspiration, only update the `ORDER BY` clause to match your ordering (which seems to be `product_position ASC, productid ASC`).

Comment: hey, perfect!! am inspired and added another answer below. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert using the normal insert query which you are using

```
  INSERT into task_schedule (taskid, productid, product_position, user_position)
  SELECT 1,1, max(product_position) + 1, 0 FROM task_schedule WHERE productid=1;
```

And then update all the entries based on product_position using the below

```
  SET @counter = 0;

  UPDATE task_schedule SET user_position = @counter := @counter + 1 ORDER BY product_position asc, productid asc;
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3994e/1)