# MySQL Update Rows with Increment Value

Tags: mysql

I've got a table containing two columns. I've removed some additional columns in this example. There are actually 5 other columns.

- dir
- msgnum

It is populated like this:

```
msgnum    dir
0         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
1         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
2         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
3         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
4         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
5         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/INBOX
0         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/Old
1         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/1/Old
0         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/2/INBOX
1         /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/test/2/INBOX
```

Note that msgnum is not unique. It is unique for each 'dir' value.

When a record is removed, I want to recalculate and update the msgnum field on each row, preserving the order of msgnum. So, if the record that has msgnum=3 is deleted, msgnum 4 and 5 are updated to 'move them up'.

Is it possible to do this in pure MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to achieve that. 
In your table go to More -> Triggers and select when it should be triggered, in this case: AFTER-DELETE, and then write your SQL. Ex.

```
UPDATE table SET msgnum = msgnum-1 WHERE msgnum > OLD.msgnum
```

where `OLD.msgnum` will be the deleted msgnum.

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: This solution doesn't account for the 'dir' field. Note that msgnum is not unique. It is unique for each 'dir' value.

Comment: @Dan_J How should one know that, if you don't tell that in your question? However - you can add the condition `AND dir = OLD.dir`

Comment: @Dan_J You shown the field, but you didn't say what do you want to do with it. I gave you only an example so you need to modify it according your app

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already executing the sql through PHP, I will answer based on that.

You need to execute the below 2 sqls in order inside a database transaction:

```
delete from mytable where msgnum = 3;
update mytable set msgnum = msgnum - 1 where msgnum > 3;
```

You need to do this inside a transaction so that if the update fails, you can safely rollback the delete also.

[Example for transaction from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)

Comment: I cant run the update until further processing is completed. More than 1 row could be deleted.

Comment: The delete sql will delete all rows matching msgnum as 3. You could do some other processing between the delete and update sqls but make sure everything is within the transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the application, I cannot put everything into one transaction. I need a way to run a SQL script which updates all the msgnum values for that 'dir', after some records have removed. Note that this PHP script is connected to Asterisk and takes feedback as it is running.

Comment: ideally, you should put all the dependent code, or the calls to the functions which actually do your 'other' things inside the transaction, because if for some reason your delete/update sql failed, then your 'other' thing should be rolled back as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find my solution so this can be considered a duplicate.

[mysql update a column with an int based on order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485769/mysql-update-a-column-with-an-int-based-on-order)